# Can I still get Skate 3 DLC on PS3?

Tags: ps3, psn, skate-3

So I'm little late on the whole console thing, since I got a PS3 almost a year after "The Last of Us" came out, because I felt I've missed out on a lot of great PS3 exclusives and PS3 prices rocketed down after the new generation came out. That's why I'm asking this question now. Looking through the trophy list on Skate 3 I noticed that there are a lot of trophies, which are part of the DLC packs that they've released years ago. I'm aware that they no longer support the "skate.Create" service so I can't get all the trophies, but I couldn't find the DLC for the game on the PS Store. So what I'm asking is if I can get the DLC, through some in-game option I haven't noticed, is the game completely unsupported now (including online content, DLC downloads, etc.) or are there some region restrictions for DLC content (I'm from Bulgaria, using a Bulgarian PSN Profile)? I do get the online features getting cut out of a 5-year old game but just deleting DLC seems weird. So is there a way I could get it or is it just gone?

Comment: Games with in-game DLC buying options often just link to the store... So if you happen to find an option like that somewhere, I would be doubtful it would work..

Comment: It might not exist since I can't find it anywhere on the PSN store but I can still find the DLC on the Xbox store, so I was wondering if there is some problem with the Playstation version (and that would be weird since they've re-released the game pretty recently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the problem is a region restriction. The game cannot be found on the Bulgarian PSN store, but all DLC is still available for purchase in many other stores like the US, UK or Germany.

What you could do, although this would probably be an inconvenience, is set up a new PSN account with another region to purchase the DLC from there.

You can get a look at the DLC by accessing the UK PSN store on PC through [this link](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-gb/games/skate-3/cid=EP0006-BLES00760_00-DISCONLYPARENT00%3AADD-ONS) (you have to be logged out of your PSN on the site or it will automatically redirect to your region).

As a side note: The servers of the game don't seem to be offline yet, so [according to this thread](http://psnprofiles.com/forums/topic/34412-platinum-unobtainable-artsy-fartsy-issue/unread/) it might still be possible (but glitchy) to get all trophies.

Comment: I can't imagine why I haven't tried that. I already had a UK PSN account for content I couldn't access. And yeah, servers are available but skate.Create isn't so you can't upload your parks, graphics and the like. However, It's still weird that I can buy the game in my country but I can't buy the DLC. Thank you for the answer because it also means that I can now buy Skate 2 DLC, too.